Отключение выполнения скрипта
Несколько сайтов на битриксе подверглись атаке, с главных страниц идёт редирект на левые сайты. Зараженных файлов много, вручную чистить долго.
Можно ли как-то на время скриптом отключить скрипты, начинающиеся на <script src="data:text/javascript;base64,?

Content Security Policy

Не помогает, все равно скрипты грузятся
